# Form submission not generating new Post object

Tags: python, django, forms, models

I'm currently creating a Social platform with Django. Right now, I'm developing their Dashboard and want endusers to be able to publish their own posts. This is my Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    Likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

My Form for the Post model:

```
class Post_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
             'content',
            ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].label = ""
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs={
            'id': 'id_content',
            'class': 'myCustomClass',
            'name': 'name_content',
            'placeholder': 'What are you thinking about?',
        }
```

When the form gets submitted, it correctly generates a POST request with the value of the content field. When I save my form in the view, no new post gets generated. What am I doing wrong?

My views.py:

```
def dashboard_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = Post_form(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save() // <- no new post gets generated after saving
            return redirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('settings'))
    else:
        form = Post_form
        gebruikers = User.objects.all()
        all_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-posted')
        return render(request, 'Dashboard/index.html', {'gebruiker':gebruikers, 'posts':all_posts, 'form': form},)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the user as the instance parameter to a Post form. You should omit that argument and assign the user on the actual Post instance returned from save.

```
form = Post_form(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    post = form.save(commit=False)
    post.user = request.user
    post.save()
```